# Leaflet label is not disappearing?

Tags: label, leaflet

Hi I'm newbie at using Leaflet and trying some new features on Leaflet. I've created my own map and added leaflet label library . In [this](http://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.label/) example when mouse over the labelled areas the label appears and disappears when mouse out. But as you can see below this is not happening when I try this simple function in my map ;
[image]
Does anyone has the same problem ?

```
 function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
      layer.on({
        mouseover: highlightFeature,
        mouseout: resetHighlight,
        click: zoomToFeature
      });
  }
```

This is how I define oneachfeature func..

```
function highlightFeature(e) {
    var layer = e.target;
    var labello = layer.bindLabel('A sweet static label!');//SIKINTIII
    labello.addTo(map);//SIKINTIII
    layer.setStyle({
        weight: 3,
        color: '#f03b20',
        dashArray: '',
        fillOpacity: 0.8
      });

  }
```

And this is how I recall the function. I can't see any problem though. Why it is not working ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand the problem. This label class is a fully automated labelling system. All you have to do is add this class `onEachFeature` function like below:

```
 function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
    var labello = layer.bindLabel(feature.properties.NAME_1);
    labello.addTo(map);
      layer.on({
        mouseover: highlightFeature,
        mouseout: resetHighlight,
        click: zoomToFeature
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Very hard to "guess" from over here since you've not added any code to your question but my first one would be: You need to remove the `noHide: true` option from your `bindLabel` method's options:

Bad:

```
L.marker([0, 0]).bindLabel('My label', {noHide: true});
```

Good:

```
L.marker([0, 0]).bindLabel('My label', {noHide: false});
```

Also good:

```
L.marker([0, 0]).bindLabel('My label');
```

Reference: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.label/blob/master/README.md